When I modify the layout of a line, in a GDB ArcMap, the modification is not displayed. How can I solve this problem?
I am updating the route layout (lines) of a cartography that is in an ArcMap GDB; I have found that being in the same Feature Class, updating your layout and stopping editing, your new layout is not displayed, you still see the old one.
In this image the original layout of the tracks appears

The path was modified with respect to the background image, but the path remains the same

I edit the line and the new stroke appears on the background image, but you can see that the selection of the line in editing shows the old stroke

You observe in detail what happens

How can I solve this?

It's a file geodatabase, I'm its only user; the type of feature class is line. I have already edited several lines, before and after, but even though I have saved the session and reopened it, that entity is not updated.

"ArcMap GDB" isn't terribly clear. "Geodatabase" encompasses three or four different formats, and one of those ("enterprise") has a dozen more flavors. A save in file geodatabase should be altered immediately, but a versioned feature class could be edited and saved without being available to other users.

How did you edit the line?  It seems odd to have the two lines if you didn't create a new one.  If you snap the endpoint of the line that needs correction to the other line at its intersection, then used the reshape tool or moved individual vertices, does that move the line being edited to the location you desire?  If you have your features in a feature dataset with a topology, and you/others have any of those layers open in another project, that can block saving edits.
